# BadRequest 400 en angular al querer crear un registro

Tags: angular, asp.net, angularjs

Estoy creando una aplicación web api con el front en angular y angularMaterial, me funcionan bien al momento de crear un usuario en `Swagger UI`, pero cuando ya paso todo en Angular me da el error `BadRequest 400` cuando lo quiero crear, espero me puedan apoyar.

Este es mi servicio donde manda llamar mi API:

```
export class UsuarioService {

private urlApi: string = environment.endpoint + "Usuario/"

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

guardar(request: Usuario):Observable<ResponseApi>{
return this.http.post<ResponseApi>(`${this.urlApi}Guardar`, request)
} 
}
```

Este es mi Componente:

```
 guardarEditar_Usuario(){

const _usuario: Usuario = {
  idUsuario: this.datosUsuario == null ? "": this.datosUsuario.idUsuario,
  nombre: this.formularioUsuario.value.nombre,
  apellidos: this.formularioUsuario.value.apellidos,
  idRol: this.formularioUsuario.value.idRol,
  correo: this.formularioUsuario.value.correo,
  rolDescripcion: this.formularioUsuario.value.rolDescripcion,
  idDepartamento: this.formularioUsuario.value.idDepartamento,
  depDescripcion: this.formularioUsuario.value.depDescripcion,
  contrasena: this.formularioUsuario.value.contrasena,
  activo: parseInt(this.formularioUsuario.value.activo)
}

if(this.datosUsuario == null){

  this._usuarioServicio.guardar(_usuario).subscribe({
    next: (data) =>{
      if(data.status){
        this._utilidadServicio.mostrarAlerta("El usuario fue registrado correctamente", "Exito");
        this.modalActual.close("true")
      }else
      this._utilidadServicio.mostrarAlerta("No se pudo registrar el usuario", "Error");
    },
    error:(e) =>{}
  })

}
```

Y lo mando a llamar en el html de la siguiente manera:

```
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
        <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close color="warn">Volver</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="formularioUsuario.invalid" (click)="guardarEditar_Usuario()">{{botonAccion}}</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Pero a la hora de querer guardarlo ya con la info colocada en cada campo, me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes agregar toto el error de consola, parece ser solo un error de CORS